# ClowdWatch doesn't show any AWS lambda failure details

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to debug my lambda_function.py in AWS.
It writes the logs to CloudWatch always but..
In some case (cannot understand which) of 'Internal Server Error' it doesnt write anything but only START and END records to CloudWatch, which makes impossible to understand the root cause of the failure.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    try:
    
        print('started')
        s = psycopg2.__version__
        print(s)
        
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            user='pg_user',
            password='*********',
            host='pg_host',
            port='5432',
            database='dev_db'
        )

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select count(1) q from keywords_to_scrape")
        for q in cur:
            print(f'q = {q}')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'exception: {e} ')
    finally:
        print('returning result')

        return {
                'statusCode' : 200,
                'body' : json.dumps(f'{s}')
        }
```

and if to comment this part

```
        .............
        #conn = psycopg2.connect(
        #    user='pg_user',
        #    password='*********',
        #    host='pg_host',
        #    port='5432',
        #    database='dev_db'
        #)
        .............
```

then it perfectly writes to CloudWatch the lines "started", "exception" with clear exception message and finally returns 200 OK

But with the lines of connection to DB it just dies with 'Internal server error' and with no messages in CloudWatch.

Could you please advice how to track such failures?

Comment: Do you hit timeout error? If yes, consider to prolong your Lambda Timeout. Also if possible, please share your CloudWatch Logs

Comment: Thise are the 5 records only:
  
START RequestId: 15c7ff9a-1c98-47ab-ad04-89ccaaecf482 Version: $LATEST

started

END RequestId: 15c7ff9a-1c98-47ab-ad04-89ccaaecf482

REPORT RequestId: 15c7ff9a-1c98-47ab-ad04-89ccaaecf482 Duration: 3005.22 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 42 MB Init Duration: 166.30 ms 

2022-06-07T13:03:40.250Z 15c7ff9a-1c98-47ab-ad04-89ccaaecf482 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

You are hitting `timeout error` as according to your comment.

```
Task timed out after 3.01 seconds
```

A few things for you to try and check:

1. Make your `Lambda Timeout` longer. E.g. 10 seconds.
2. If your Lambda is still hitting `timeout error` after you longer your `Lambda Timeout`, then you might want to check your database connections to the database. E.g. Make sure your Lambda is placed in the same VPC as your database and your database security group enables traffic from your Lambda.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, this is because of timeout of lambda is less then timeout of connection to DB.